# classes returning a method value

Tags: java, class, methods

```
public class car
{
private int model;
private String make;
private double speed;
/**
 * *  My constructor
 */
public car()
{
    model = 2000;
    make= "Ferrari";
    speed= 50;

}

public int getYear()
{
    return model;
}

public String getMake()
{
    return make;
}

public double getSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}

public double accerlate ()
{
    double accerlate = speed++;
    return accerlate;
}

public void output(double accerlate)
{
    System.out.println("Year: " +model);
    System.out.println("Make: " + make);
    System.out.println("Speed: " + speed);
    System.out.println(accerlate);
}
}
```

connect to this class

```
public class RaceTrack
{
public static void main(String args[]){
   double speed = 50;
   car mycar= new car();
    mycar.getYear();
    mycar.getMake();
    mycar.getSpeed();
    mycar.output(speed);
    mycar.accerlate();
}
}
```

Anyways, I try to get an output and the accerlate method doesn't work the way I want. It should be add +1 and it is not working. Why isn't it working? It just prints the original speed.

Answer (score 2):

`double accerlate = speed++;` ==> accerlate =speed then speed =speed+1

`double accerlate = ++speed;` ==> accerlate =speed+1

For your code :
your output will be :

```
Year: 2000
Make: Ferrari
Speed: 50.0
50.0
```

this is the output of `mycar.output(speed);`the other method hasn't output in you main

```
double speed = 50;
car mycar= new car();
 mycar.getYear(); //getYear return an int (model)=2000 so store it if you want
mycar.getMake(); //getMake return a string 
mycar.getSpeed();  //getSpeed return a double =50
```

if you want to see +1 of accelerate , you should get the return of the method then print it :

```
   Double ouputSpeed=mycar.accerlate();
   System.out.println(ouputSpeed.toString()); // print 51.0
```

**To return :**

```
public double accerlate ()
{
    double accerlate = ++speed;
    return accerlate;
}
```

==> this method return a double (accerlate= spped+1 =51)

==> to get it in you main  , declare a double : `Double ouputSpeed=mycar.accerlate();` then print it .

Answer (score 0):

this is enough

```
public double accerlate ()
{
return ++speed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, use `++accelerate` instead.

However, the program as it stands will always print the speed 50 because of this

```
double speed = 50;
mycar.output(speed);
```

then the argument of `output()` is passed straight to the last `System.out.println()` in that method. Furthermore, the calls to `getYear()`, `getMake()` and `getSpeed()` in main arent actually doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you have to be careful with when writing a method in Java is storing values to variables and then returning those variables. Returning variables can cause your data to become stale. In other words java thinks that something like int or double has not value. Anyway to prevent this especially when increasing or decreasing these values is to make sure you initialize these variables with a value such as zero. Which is something you don't do in your code. That may be why

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your problem:

```
public double accerlate ()
{
    return ++speed;
}
```

Also, I have noticed that you have created a `speed` variable in your `main` method. I am not sure you need that one.

Answer (score 0):

ok, the var double speed = 50; is local in the method, and this will be global

```
public class car
{
private int model;
private String make;
private double speed;
private double accerlate // you need make the getter and setter
/**
 * *  My constructor
 */
public car()
{
    model = 2000;
    make= "Ferrari";
    speed= 50;

}

public int getYear()
{
    return model;
}

public String getMake()
{
    return make;
}

public double getAccelerate()
{
 return accelerate;
 }
public double setAccelerate(double accelerate)
{
  this.accelerate = accelerate;
}

public double getSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}

public double accerlate ()
{
    accerlate = speed++;
    return accerlate;
}

public void output(double accerlate)
{
    System.out.println("Year: " +model);
    System.out.println("Make: " + make);
    System.out.println("Speed: " + speed);
    System.out.println(accerlate);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public double accerlate ()
{
    double accerlate = speed+1;
    return accerlate;
}
```

++ is different than +1, ++ means the operation happens AFTER the assigning of the value, however +1 will happen before hand, could also do ++speed.

Comment: it not doing the method, the accerlate is the same as the speed.